# Hide element only if javascript is enabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views, javascript

I have a view that displays a textbox as follows:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CodeGuest, new {style = "display: none"})
```

it is displayed via javascript (so the user clicks a checkbox).

If javascript is not enabled, I must remove this line (`style = "display: none"`) so that the textbox is displayed by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use client side logic for this, have it visible as default and hide it with javascript on page load.

If you use jQuery it will be something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('[name="CodeGuest"]').hide();
});
```

And remove the display: none from the Razor logic.

Another solution is to wrap the textbox element in `<noscript>`-tags.

For example:

```
<noscript>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CodeGuest)
</noscript>
```

Comment: There's this tag, called `<noscript>`, whose content is only shown if JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: That is actually superior since it won't risk that the element will flicker on page load, added it to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I typed this as a comment because it seemed so obvious I figured somebody else could grab some upvotes, but:

```
<noscript>
  <div>
    Hello YOU HAVE JAVASCRIPT TURNED OFF YOU BIG SILLY
  </div>
</noscript>
```

The content of a `<noscript>` tag is shown only when JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: That msg will not be applicable to UAs that are not JS-*capable*. Furthermore, UAs w/ poor JS implementations may not reliably display the <noscript> contents. A catch-all solution would be to use JS that runs immediately to remove DOM elements that are not applicable to JS-capable/enabled UAs, as some of the other answers have shown.

Comment: So how common are UAs without understanding of the `<noscript>` tag in 2011?

Answer (score 3):

The way I generally handle this is by hiding the elements initially ***WITH*** javascript when the Dom loads... This way, no javascript = no hiding...

Comment: seriously? run js instead of using noscript tag for this seems like shooting birds with canons

Comment: @Martin Jespersen: I think, that he still needs the element in the DOM, because he is going to display the text-box after a checkbox is clicked. So I think hiding it via JS would be a perfectly acceptable way for doing this

Comment: There's at least some indication that this is dynamic manipulation, and not so simple as dumping the element inside a noscript block; otherwise, there'd be no point in ever hiding the element. Seems to me like a JS solution could be just as good as a noscript.

Answer (score 3):

The way I generally prefer to do this, to avoid the flashing of the content on long pages when using the JS hiding solution, is to add something like this to the CSS:

```css
html.jsEnabled #CodeGuest {display: none;}
```

and then in the JS, just add this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className += ' jsEnabled';
```

The advantage is that you can run that bit of code even before the DOM is Ready, since the HTML tag will already be available. Plus I can use that class for any other progressive enhancements I might have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I like Pointy's answer, but here's a simple script option:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write('<style type="text/css">#hideMe {display:none;}<\/style>');
</script>
```

While a noscript element is elegant, it is not consistent with the principles of feature and capability detection and graceful degredation. A better strategy is to decide whether to show the element or not **only** if the browser is capable of running the associated script.

The above suggestion has the same drawback.

Answer (score 1):

You can just hide the element with JavaScript, so the element is displayed by default.
Only if JavaScript is executed, the element is hidden.

I don't know what markup your given code generates, but with JavaScript you could do something like this (for a simple-case example, when the element gets an id):

```
elem = document.getElementById(id);
elem.style.display = 'none';
```

So it will get hidden, when JavaScript is enabled. Be sure to wait, until the DOM is fully loaded, before you execute your script, otherwise this could end up doing nothing.

For DOM-Manipulation, I tend to use jQuery, it has a good DOM-ready Listener and easy element-selection.